# rotate imageview using viewflipper in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want  to ratotate image from right to left.
how can i rotate it using viewflipper?

```
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromDegrees="90" android:toDegrees="90" android:pivotX="100%"
    android:pivotY="100%" android:duration="500" />
```

like above but i want to rotate it from right to left.

Answer (score 0):

Never done this before but since it's mathematical, try adding a "minus" to the 90, might work, might not.

Answer (score 0):

The rotation is apparantly defined in degrees, 360 degrees would make a full rotation. If your current rotation is in the wrong direction for you, try rotating 270 degrees (or 3/4th) or like Androider said, -90 degrees.

Answer (score 0):

You can give from degree as 0 and to degree as 359 in rotate.since 0 and 360 are same. I didnt try it.may be it will help you.